# Python GUI TKINTER SQLITE3 error for the following code

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter

**CODE:-**

```
def datasave():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('lpugym.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO lpugym(name,phone) VALUES (?,?),(name.get(), phone.get();')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO lpugym ((phone) VALUES (phone.get())')
    if var.get()==1 :
        c.execute('INSERT INTO lpugym ((gender) VALUES (Male)')
    else:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO lpugym ((gender) VALUES (Female)')
    if var2.get()==1 :
            c.execute('INSERT INTO lpugym ((package) VALUES (Monthly)')
    if var2.get()==2 :
            c.execute('INSERT INTO lpugym ((package) VALUES (Yearly)')
    global price
    if var2.get()==1 :
            price=2500*var1.get()
            c.execute('INSERT INTO lpugym ((price) VALUES (price)')
    if var2.get()==2 :
            price=2450*var1.get()*12
            c.execute('INSERT INTO lpugym ((price) VALUES (price)')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO lpugym ((address) VALUES (address.get())')
    c.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

**Output**

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  line 1702, in **call**
    `return self.func(*args)`
  File "S:editable.py", line 105, in datasave
    `c.executemany('INSERT INTO lpugym(name,phone,gender,package,price,address) VALUES (?,?),(name.get(), phone.get();')`
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: what is the `;'` in the end?

Comment: it need to be formated as 2 arguments 1 the sql 2 the args

Comment: can u explain me in detail ?

Answer (score 1):

Add another bracket to the end of the `phone.get()` in the `.executemany` statement.

`c.executemany('INSERT INTO lpugym(name,phone) VALUES (?,?), (name.get(), phone.get()))`